# merge postgis schema with FME

Tags: postgis, fme-form, postgresql-10

I have a spatial postgis database named "testdata" having two schema named "afgdata" and "pakdata" with common table names viz. building_a, places, railways, roads, water_a, waterways of different area.

[image: afgdata]

[image: pakdata]

I am not familiar with both Postgis and FME.

I want to merge both schema in to new schema  named "mergedata" within same database. Can anybody help me out to do it with FME or direct in PostgreSQL?

Is it possible to merge both schema and output in new database in public schema?

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use `UNION` in PostgreSQL.

For example,

```
WITH waterways AS (
    SELECT * FROM afg_data.waterways
  UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM pak_data.waterways
)
SELECT * FROM waterways;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, it works. But what for multiple tables?

Comment: The example does have multiple tables.

Comment: Yes in image places, buildings, roads, railways.

Comment: Depending on how many there are and if it's going to be automated, either just write a manual query, or use another query to list the tables in each schema, and use that intermediate result to produce the final query. You might have some issues because your table names are inconsistent (`buildings` and `buildings_a`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644152/list-tables-in-a-postgresql-schema

Comment: I have only following layer : building_a, places, railways, roads, water_a and waterways in both database of different area. Is this possible to merge all layers in a new database or existing database having the same layer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. The above will merge two tables with the same table schema, into one table. You can store this in a new schema in the same database, or dump it to a different database. These are all standard database management tasks that you fall outside the scope of GIS.SE.